# How can I omit permanenty logged snap livepatch messages?

Tags: syslog, canonical-livepatch

I'm using Ubuntu 20.04 with Ubuntu Pro.

Running the following command:

```
canonical-livepatch disable
```

results in the error:

```
error executing disable: livepatchd error: daemon shutting down
```

I permanently get the following messages in syslog with different numbers before scope:

```
Apr 26 21:06:12 jufi1 systemd[1091]: Started snap.canonical-livepatch.canonical-livepatch.033933e6-fcce-47d0-9a2f-55b9dff9ba82.scope.
Apr 26 21:06:12 jufi1 systemd[1091]: snap.canonical-livepatch.canonical-livepatch.033933e6-fcce-47d0-9a2f-55b9dff9ba82.scope: Succeeded.
```

I have livepatch disabled.

How can I suppress these log entries from spamming every 10 seconds?

Comment: Now i have removed the livepatch snap with "snap remove canonical-livepatch"